# spark recommendtion Rating user int

Tags: int, apache-spark, rating, userid

As the spark API, Rating.user type is Int
Rating(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double)
But the userid in my system is out of range Int, for example: 2147896135
there is an error reported when I run the ALS.train():

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2147896135"
        java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Any idea on this issue?